# Git Commit: replacement, no merging

Tags: git, commit

I have a repo of recent code.  The repo was started after version 5 of the code.

The versions 1 through 4 are in a different SCM (version 5 was created by porting version 4 to git).

I am tasked with making changes to version 4.
I have created a new branch off of version 5.
I replaced all the files (except git related) from version 5 with version 4.

```
(Version 5)
 |
 +---+
 |   |
 |   +--> Version 4 upgraded
 |
 | (Version 6)
```

Version 4 will not be merged into Version 5.

How can I commit my branch (to local server) without performing any code merges?

Comment: Not sure to understand the question: commit, and push your branch `version4`. If you don't do a merge it won't happen automatically

Comment: I want a copy of Version4 repo committed to my local server.  No merging, just transmitted verbatim.  I don't want to merge my Version 4 with any Version 5 code.

Comment: There was probably a better way to bring version 4 into Git than to branch off version 5 and replace every file. But you are asking a non-question: nothing will be merged with Version 5 unless *you* merge it. If your version-4 branch is checked out (*did* you check it out?), then any commits on that branch will not be part of the version 5 branch.

Comment: I performed a `git checkout -b Version4`, then replaced all the files.  Do I need to run `commit`?

Comment: It's not clear that version 4 even needs to be in the same repository, unless you will *eventually* merge the changes into version 5.

Comment: You need a tutorial on how to use Git.

Comment: I was told by management to put everything into one repository.

Comment: Yes you need to commit. I'd recommend reading the basics of Git.if you are going to use it !

Comment: "version 5 was created by porting version 4 to git" Are version 4 (before your updates) and 5 the same?

Comment: Regarding this comment, "I was told by management to put everything into one repository", does "everything" include versions prior to version 4 too?

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to merge, then simply don't merge. If you need to push a branch to a remote server, do so:

```
git push origin version4:version4
```

pushes your local branch `version4` to the remote repository configured as `origin` and names the branch in the remote repo `version4` too.

Of course, the branch needs to contain commits to be pushed. If you haven't committed your local unstaged changes yet, now is the perfect time to do it:

```
git add -u # stage all changed and removed files
git add newfiles...
git commit -m 'Committing version 4'
```

Comment: What about using `commit`?
I'm used to using GitLab and merging.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews what do you mean with commit? As I understood your question, you have already deleted all v5 code and replaced it with v4 code, then committed the new state. Did I not understand that correctly?

Comment: At this point, I have created a branch, and replaced contents with Version4.  I have not committed the new state.  I have not pushed.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews In that case, commit, then push

Answer (score 0):

I'm no sure I understood your question correctly, probably it needs some refinements, but I'll do my best to provide some ideas that might lead to the acceptable solution.

I'll also try to keep it as simple as possible GIT wise because I feel that you're not really familiar with git (sorry if I'm wrong, just trying to help, you know).
So I'll describe a "theoretical approach" to a possible "resolution" of your situation

Git can maintain multiple "remote" branches, right? Usually people use to work with "master" branch (or in some organization there is a "dev" branch), etc. But in general git can keep many remote branches and you'll chose on which branch to work at any period of time.

The branch is a pointer on a codebase snapshot, lets say a series of files in a specified state.

So you have a "version 5" branch that you're usually work with, its a remote branch from which you pull the code, make modifications, commit stuff and push from time to time, right? I assume that's your day2day routine.

Now you've mentioned two things:

1. version 5 was initially created out of version 4 by porting from another CSM to git. From this I conclude that the first commit to "version 5" branch contained just the same files as version 4 did. Then you've made more commits and the branch has evolved
2. Your task is to make changes to version 4. From this one I conclude that you have two choices:

- If in your organization there is a decision to keep version 4 in another CSM, why do you even mess with version 5 and git? Keep doing it in an "old way" and commit to the old CSM. If you will need to port it to version 5 in git - create a patch and apply it.
- If you really want to move version 4 to git as well, you should consider creating a different branch out of the first commit of "version 5" (which is, by my assumption is identical to version 4).
  Then you should do the changes to that version (by committing your work to that branch) and **push it** as a different remote branch (next to already existing "version5")

So you'll end up with two different branches in the "remote" repo - "version 4" and "version 5" that will never be merged one to another. In git its perfectly possible.
If you don't want to merge - then just don't do that.

Let me know whether this is an acceptable situation "in theory" - and if it is - please specify whether you have technical difficulties with concrete git commands so that our colleagues and me could help... I'm not really familiar with gitlab that you've mentioned, so this question is valid from a "plain git" standpoint I believe, but again, if you'll provide more details probably people will come up with concrete commands that will work for you best.

Answer (score 0):

Let first state that I was confused about staging and merging.

I used GitExtensions to add all the Version 4 files to the staging area, then committed and pushed the "changes".

My original understanding is that the files identified as changed (between version 4 and version 5) would be merged.  Nothing was merged.  The GitExtensions shows the files that have changed and their diffs.  Since Version 4 is different than Version 5, there was changes.

All is working good now.